# How can a google slide automatically become full screen

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am working on a blogger page.
https://peacepakistan1.blogspot.com/2016/10/blog-post.html

It contain a google slide. My task is to detect if the user is on PC then google slide will remain as it is.

But if a user is on mobile then the Google slide will automatically open in **full screen mode**

First i am working on click on button then i will go to the mobile part !!

[image: button to be clicked]

I have got a script to do it but it does not work.

```
function clickButton(val)
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('goog-inline-block goog-flat-button');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    {
       if(buttons[i].type == 'submit' && buttons[i].value == val) 
       {
           buttons[i].click();
           break; //this will exit for loop, but if you want to click every button with the value button then comment this line
       }
    }
}

clickButton('continue');
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `getElementsByTagName` but passing a class name, that wont work, try using `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('goog-inline-block goog-flat-button');  does not worked too.

Answer (score 0):

The slide elements are contained inside their own iframe. You need to be accessing the iframe.

First, use `var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` to get an array of all iframes on your page and then enumerate them all and work inside that.